# Unable to view/customize Entities when change the language other than the base language in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am unable to customize/view the entities when I change the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 language other than the base language. Any guidance to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can customize Dynamics CRM (create/modify entities, attributes, system views, ...) only using the base language.

There are no fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can partly work with customization and your local language by first opening the customization page or the form editor using the base language and then changing to your local language.